# Unable to create a spot instance VM in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-vm

I have been trying to create a spot instance Standard D2s v3 (2 vcpus, 8 GiB memory) VM in my MSDN Azure subscription. I have tried EastUS, EastUS2 and WestUS regions with the same result.

> The requested size for resource
>   '/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/dnd/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/windowsvm'
>   is currently not available in location 'eastus2' zones '' for
>   subscription 'xxxxx'. Please try another size or deploy to a different
>   location or zones. See https://aka.ms/azureskunotavailable for
>   details.'.'. (Code: InvalidTemplateDeployment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most like you should open a ticket to Microsoft, I was not able to create a spot instance for MSDN Subcription neither, but I was for pay-as-you-go Subscription, I choose the same size, region etc. Alternately you can try to contact Microsoft Q&A specifically for Azure Spot (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/topics/azure-spot.html).

Comment: I was having the exact same issue. No matter what vm or region I tried spot instances would not work using my MSDN Azure subscription.

Comment: @Smolakian did you find a solution? I can't even open a support ticket without paying for a support plan!